# RegEx for omitting part of URL to ahead of domain name

Tags: javascript, regex, split

I need to do the following n javascript using regex and split function:

input: http://www.google.com/some-page.html
output: http://www.google.com

I tried the following, but it doesnt work, it just returns "http://www.google."

```
href = href.split("com/")[0];
```

I am sure I must have made some noob mistake but sorry I am new to this! Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can use this:

```
var firstPart = href.match(/^(.+?:\/\/.+?)\//)[1];
```

Working demo: http://jsfiddle.net/jfriend00/xJkLD/

Comment: Yeah, sorry about that.  I fixed it and now include a working demo.

Answer (score 1):

```
/https?:\/\/[^/]*/.exec('http://www.google.com/search-page.html')
```

output:

["http://www.google.com"]

Answer (score 0):

Got it! I used this:

```
 href = href.match("(http:\/\/.+.com)")[0];
```

Comment: I don't know how general you want this to be, but this won't work if it's `https://` and it won't work if the suffix on the domain isn't .com .  The other proposed solutions are more general purpose.

Comment: That is true. I actually only need a solution for the ".com" websites but yes the "http(s)" bit needs to be taken care of. The other solutions are far better, I agree!